# Splitted namespace in header file

Tags: c++, namespaces

I'm currently working on an existing c++ project.

During code analysis i found header files, containing namespace definition split up in two parts(see **c1.h**). First part containing forward-declarations and second part containing the class declaration.

**c1.h**

```
namespace a { namespace b {
    class c2;
    class c3;
}} 

namespace a { namespace b {
    class c1
    {
        public:
            //...
        private:
            //...
    };
}}
```

**c1_foo.h**

```
namespace a { namespace b {
    class c2;
    class c3;

    class c1_foo
    {
        public:
            //...
        private:
            //...
    };
}}
```

**My question:**

Is there any reason for splitting this up into two logical parts? Does **c1_foo.h** declare anything different?  I've never seen this before...

Thx for your help!

Comment: Is just a matter of coding style, this developer want to have at the start of file all the forward-declarations, maybe if you have like 4-5 classes in this file, is easier to find what you look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no functional difference at all.

Apparently the programmer likes to keep forward declarations entirely separate, which actually kind of makes stylistic sense now that I think about it.